# How to add security rule for sub maps with a different id in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to add security rule, that the quantity of the product cannot be less than zero.

[image: Text]
request from client side:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
       .collection('$collectionPath')
       .doc('$uid')
       .update({'cart items.$itemId.quantity': FieldValue.increment(-1)});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Firebase documentation [data validation on security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation):

> ```
> service cloud.firestore {
>  match /databases/{database}/documents {
>    // Make sure all cities have a positive population and
>    // the name is not changed
>    match /cities/{city} {
>      allow update: if request.resource.data.population > 0
>                    && request.resource.data.name == resource.data.name;
>    }
>  }
> }
> ```

So your condition would be in the `write`, `create` or `update` rule and be `request.resource.data.quantity >= 0`.